# How to replace strings with other strings via .replace method in python?

Tags: python, string, replace

I'm trying to do the following:

Replace any inputted strings, with "HA!". How many they are, is dependent on how many letters there are in the string (three letters means three "HA!"s, etc)

CODE:

```
stringI = input("Enter anything in here! It will become laughter after 
you do this! \n")
if stringI.isalpha:
    print(stringI.replace(stringI, "HA!", len(stringI)))
```

It outputs only one "HA!", regardless of the number of chars in the string.

Comment: You're not replacing letters, you're replacing the whole string. Also you're not *calling* `isalpha`. I think you should try to solve this on paper before attempting an implementation.

Comment: Also, why replace anything if you can construct a new string with `"HA!"`s?

Comment: `if stringI.isalpha:` is always true. Should be `if stringI.isalpha():`

Comment: Why is `isalpha` relevant here at all anyway? Nowhere in your requirement does it mention numbers. You just need to call `len()` on the string.

Comment: @roganjosh "dependent on how many letters there are in the string" says "letters" rather than "characters"

Comment: @PatrickHaugh fair, but i think it's a push on the problem as-stated. I was more curious about why `isalpha` is the only method the OP has implemented. What, based on the requirements, should happen to numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the above comments that it's not really necessary to use the replace method because you're really just making a new string. Here's a simple way to do it that's pretty easy to visualize:

```
>>> count = 0
>>> stringI = input("Enter anything in here! It will become laughter after you do this\n")
Enter anything in here! It will become laughter after you do this
test test
>>> count = 0
>>> for char in stringI:
...     if char.isalpha():
...         count += 1
... 
>>> str_builder = ''
>>> for ha in range(count):
...     str_builder += "HA! "
... 
>>> str_builder
'HA! HA! HA! HA! HA! HA! HA! HA! '
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways of doing this:

1. Loop over the string to build a new string, replacing letters with `HA!`

   ```
   def make_ha(s):
       return "".join(["HA!" if c.isalpha() else c for c in s])
   ```
2. Make a translation table and use that to translate strings

   ```
   from string import ascii_letters

   trans = str.maketrans(dict.fromkeys(ascii_letters, "HA!"))

   def make_ha2(s):
       return s.translate(trans)
   ```

The first is a little simpler to understand, while the second will get complicated less quickly if you start adding other rules later.  The later also works only for ascii letters, while the former will operate based on the Unicode definition of an alphabetic character.

```
print(make_ha("aaBB123"))  # HA!HA!HA!HA!123
print(make_ha2("aaBB123")) # HA!HA!HA!HA!123
```